# Run Xamarin Android Blank Application on device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to figure out with Xamarin Android Blank Application basics. I use Visual Studio 2015 and C# on PC Windows 10

But each time I make some changes in my code, I got deployment errors massage window with debugging and can't run emulator through time. If I start a new project with copy/paste of MainActivity.cs content from broken project and proper Main.axml interface, same code works. then if I add something new to new project code, or just restart VS deployment errors appears again, with only output below. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, rebuild does not helps in this case

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Android_App, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Android_App -> D:\folder\Android_App\bin\Debug\Android_App.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>Please select a valid device before running the application.
2>------ Deploy started: Project: Android_App, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Error: Cancelled
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

So, now I'm trying to run into device:

1. I've installed Android SDK with Android SDK Manager from Visual Studio
2. Build Number
3. Developer Options, USB debugging
4. USB Connection by default I checked Media Device (MPT)
5. Google USB driver is also installed and it is inside C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\extras\google\usb_driver
6. in my Device Manager after Updating of Driver Software and Browse my Computer for Driver Software by path above with include sub folders checking, I see Portable Device/MyPhone and Samsung Android Phone/Samsung Android ADB Interface.

I did not installed driver for my Samsung Phone because I already can see new category Samsung Android Phone/Samsung Android ADB Interface I guess

So in Devices of Android Device Monitor I see my Phone as number not the name, and its status is Online

In VS2015 it is checked now as Samsung SM-G3815 (Android 4.2 - API 17)) for Android_App1, where is also: Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23) and Android_ARMv7a (Android 6.0 - API 23)

Deployment error is gone, but it's just starts debug without any window and automatically stops debugging process in few seconds.

In Solutions Properties/Application:

- Compile using Android version: Use Latest Platform (Android
  6.0(Marshmallow))
- Minimum Android to target: Android 4.1 (API Level 16 - Jelly Bean)
- Target Android Version: Use Compile using SDK version

and same result with Minimum Android to target: Android 4.2 (API Level 16 - Jelly Bean) and Compile using Android version has only Use Latest Platform (Android 6.0(Marshmallow))

So I'm not sure how to go further, how to run it

**Edit:**

logcat final line:

```
02-22 22:13:03.843  Samsung SM-G3815    Warning 31153   System.err      at com.ksmobile.business.sdk.data_manage.k.run(DataManager.java:109)02-22 22:36:04.811 D/Mono    (32250): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-armv7/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Collections.dll.so' not found: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:746): library "/data/app-lib/Android_App1.Android_App1-8/libaot-System.Collections.dll.so" not found
```

and there is also a lot of different errors, not only these:

```
02-22 22:31:05.091  Samsung SM-G3815    Error   1340    Auth        at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.o.a(:com.google.android.gms:260)
02-22 22:31:05.091  Samsung SM-G3815    Error   1340    Auth        at com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.dataservice.x.a(:com.google.android.gms:558)
02-22 22:31:05.091  Samsung SM-G3815    Error   1340    Auth        at com.google.android.gms.auth.o.a(:com.google.android.gms:276)
02-22 22:31:05.091  Samsung SM-G3815    Error   1340    Auth        at com.google.android.gms.auth.o.a(:com.google.android.gms:196)
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots and `adb logcat` logs of what you are experiencing?

Comment: @Jon Douglas Hello, I've edit my question. Since I'm a newbie with xamarin and android, I'm not sure, how to read logcat. Content is large. not sure if I have to add it here completely. Anyway if it makes sense, let me know, I just need to figure out how to add text document on stackoverflow. therefore I've add final line of 8564 lines of my logcat, and several errors above

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the output build logs by extending the trace log.
Go to tools->xamarin->output verbosity, set level to diagnostic and check the detailed build error you have.

Comment: Hello, I don't have xamarin in tools, there is only xamarin account and android tools. It is not the same, right, if I must go to Device (logcat) of  Android Toll Bar options and choose device?